# Cross-platform Desktop directory path?

Tags: python, path, directory, cross-platform, desktop

Is there a way of obtaining the **Desktop directory path** in a *cross-platform* way, ideally only using standard modules, in Python?

My current Mac OS X + Windows solution is to check which system is running Python with [sys.platform](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.platform) and then do the following:

- Mac OS X can be handled with `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop')`.
- [Windows](http://ginstrom.com/scribbles/2008/09/26/retrieving-common-windows-folder-names-with-python/) can use the non-standard module `win32com`, or the ctypes-dependent module [winpaths](http://ginstrom.com/code/winpaths.html); is there a standard alternative?
- And what about Linux?

I would be happy with a solution that works on Mac OS X, Windows and Linux.

Comment: They are different operating systems.  The trivial answer is almost universally "No", there is no standard that applies to both families of operating systems.  Windows is non-standard.  Are you perhaps asking for a way to minimize the differences?  Please post the code you're using so we can -- perhaps -- simplify it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3413/discussion-between-eol-and-s-lott)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Underneath windows, the users home is `%HOMEPATH%` which is the equivalent of the linux and Mac `~`. Underneath this, there is a folder `Desktop` just like on Mac. Python automatically converts `~` to %HOMEPATH% on windows, so your Mac command will work out of the box on Mac and Windows.

On Linux, it's a bit trickier. First, understand that the Linux box you are running on may not *have* a desktop, so no user desktop folder. If you do have window manager, it may or may not follow the `~\Desktop` paradigm. [The wikipedia entry on window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_manager) goes into far more detail, including comparisons between several of the more popular X window managers in some of the sublinks.

Your best bet would be to step back, and ask yourself *why do I want/need the users desktop folder?* Is it to create a shortcut during the install? You are likely better off with a installation writer utility, such as [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), handling those details. If it's for file storage, even temporary, you may want to rethink your design. Or are you looking for something, in which case a file system search may be the way to go, instead of a brittle single folder check.

Like most things, it all depends on what you want to accomplish.

As EOL noted in his comment, Windows is slightly trickier than it first appears. [His link to a more complete article on the Windows Desktop](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/719464-how-create-file-users-xp-desktop) folder has more details on localization for the desktop folder. This is very important for builders of international applications to take into account, either using automatic localization built into their toolset, or avoiding things that use it.

Comment: Thank you for the comments on Linux.  As for Windows, it does sometimes puts the Desktop under a localized directory name (http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/719464-how-create-file-users-xp-desktop), so it looks like the win2com approach is better, no?

Comment: I'm interested in the Desktop path because (1) The user runs programs (from a USB key) that create many output files. These files should not go to the USB key, because users may not be able to keep the key. (2) These output files should also be made easily "visible" to the user, so that he finds them easily, hence the Desktop idea.

Comment: @EOL thanks for the link, I wasn't aware of that. For the output, wouldn't it be simpler to tell the user where you put the files, and/or open a explorer window to show the directory? Ideally, we should create a new subfolder, to avoid mixing the new files into their stuff, in case they want to delete them easily.

Comment: Yeah, the programs do create a common output directory so as to avoid mixing their output with the user's files.  Opening an explorer window is unfortunately not practical, as users run multiple programs many times, and they can't afford having a window pop each time. :)  Thanks for sharing ideas, though. :)

Comment: @EOL no problem, though I was just struck with a thought. If the user has to run this from a usb key, then they know when the program is run. Presumably, either because of a message upon completion, or an educated userbase, they will also know that that they need to do something with the output files. If they don't actually need them, perhaps the output directory should be more of a long term storage thing?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The users are actually non-specialists who don't know much about the programs and who are mostly interested in the outputs.  :)  I'll mark your answer as accepted if you update it with the point that I mentioned about Windows being a little trickier.

Comment: @EOL I've added a section on windows localization, though I think the best thing to do would be to avoid a desktop folder entirely. It sounds like that won't work though, which may indicate a need to rework the way the tool operates.  I don't know enough about the problem to make that decision though. Best of luck!

Answer (score 20):

I used the following:

```
import os
desktop_file = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/myfile.txt")
```

> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with an initial component of
>   ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home directory.

Reference: os.path.[expanduser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Comment: This answer actually returns the `PYTHON DEFAULT PATH ENVIRONMENT`, it didn't worked for me.