# Python local folder path for each platform

Tags: python, directory

My script works in special folder, which name is "Fold".
On the different computers and operation systems path to this folder is different.
For example, on Mac it will: "/Users/user/Fold". On Windows - "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Fold" .
How I can input the path to this folder in my Python script for working on each platform? What should I type inside my script, if the script works only inside "Fold" folder?

Comment: `Desktop` does not fit the theme. You'll have to special-case it if you insist on it. It would, however, make more sense as `c:\Users\user\Fold`, `c:\Users\user\AppData\Fold` or `c:\Users\user\Documents\Fold`.

Answer (score 1):

the os module has the functionality for identifying various operating systems

in your code you can do this

```
import os

if os.name == 'nt'
    # do something nt stands for windows
    path = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Fold'
elif os.name == 'posix'
    # linux or mac
    path = '/home/user/Desktop/Fold'
```

the platform module gives more details than the os module the os might return posix for both linux and mac on my linux machine platform outputs this

```
import platform

>>> print(platform.system())
Linux
>>> print(platform.release())
3.13.0-76-generic
```

`platform.system()` should return 'Darwin' for mac

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import sys
import os
sys.platform == "win32":
    fold = os.path.join("C:", "Users", "user", "Desktop", "Fold")
elif sys.platform == "Darwin":
    fold = os.path.join("/Users", "user", "Fold")
else:
    ...
```

Or you can setup an environment variable on each computer if it changes within a same OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the path to the user folder (Mac: `/Users/user`, Win: `C:\Users\user\`) via [os.path.expanduser("~")](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser). From there, your implementation seems OS-specific - maybe only the Windows-implementation places its data on the desktop. Since you can get the platform identifier via [sys.platform](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sys.html#sys.platform), you could do something like this:

```
import sys, os
folderPath = os.path.join("Desktop", "Fold") if sys.platform == "win32" else "Fold"
fullPath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), folderPath)
```

If you want to use the path to the desktop folder on other systems, please refer to [Cross-platform Desktop directory path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403918/cross-platform-desktop-directory-path)