# Error when verifying folder creation (Python)

Tags: python, subprocess, directory, expanduser

I am stuck in an "error" during my folder creation. 
First of all, this is the code I am using:

```
import os
import errno
import subprocess

try:
    folder = os.makedirs(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\FOLDER'))
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
print(os.path.isdir('~\\Desktop\\FOLDER'), '- FOLDER CREATED')
```

So, the code do the following:

- using `os.makedirs()` it creates a new folder on Desktop. I want to create a folder which use cross-platform path, so I am using `~` symbol
- using `print()` I want to verify that the folder really exist, that the directory is real. The output of this is `True` or `False`.

The problem is: if I am using the `~` symbol in `print()`, the output is `False`. If I put the complete path to the folder (ex: `os.path.isdir('C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\FOLDER')`, the output is `True`.

Why does this happen ? The folder is really created even if I have a False output ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403918/cross-platform-desktop-directory-path

Comment: It'd be better if you just created a variable to store the expanded path and use that where necessary: `path = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\Folder')`.  Then use `path` as the argument to `os.makedirs()` and `os.path.isdir()`.  This help reduce errors such as this one.

Comment: I tried doing that but it gives me an error...Will try again just now. Thanks BTW. Also, the problem is that I have some nested folders, more complex than just one with (concatenad) variables in path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing the `expanduser` method when calling isdir:

```
print(os.path.isdir(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\FOLDER')), '- FOLDER CREATED')
```

You don't really need the check at the end as well. Since if there is no exception, you can be sure that the creation is successful.

Here is a cleaner implementation:

```
try:
    dirpath = os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\FOLDER')
    os.makedirs(dirpath)
    print dirpath, "creation successful"
except OSError as e:
    print dirpath, "creation failed"
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
```